# How do I increase the volume beyond 100% in Kubuntu?

Tags: sound, kubuntu

The Unity/gtk volume manager that comes with vanilla Ubuntu lets you increase the volume past 100%, which is useful for hearing quiet youtube videos. Is there a way to achieve the same thing with the KDE mixer app?

Answer (score 4):

Left click on the KMix plasmoid then on "Configure Channels" button:

[image]

In the "General" section of the widget settings check "Volume Overdrive" checkbox.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work on Kubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 2):

im not to familair with KDE but,
you could try using the alsamixer program in the terminal

[image: the alsamixer program]

Comment: Works like a charm. Increasing "Master" has the desired effect. I guess when the usual UI fails we have to stick to the old school terminal. :)

Comment: Wait, I have right now alsamixer open. "Master" is all the way up and I am unable to increase beyond 100%. Am I forgetting something?.

Comment: it doesnt go over 100%...

Answer (score 1):

KDE's volume manager now (~ version 5.17) has an option to "Raise Maximum volume", this allows volume above 100%, till 150%. In few of the earlier versions, configuration of of the same had a "Maximum volume" field.

[image: Plasma volume manager]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this (in my case, as all the volumes in `alsamixer` were to the maximum) was using Veromix.

First install python script engine, `sudo apt-get install plasma-scriptengine-python`. Then right click your destop and select the option add widgets. Select the option "Get new Windgets" and "Download new plasma widgets", then in the search box type in "Veromix".

[image: Veromix]

Once you have it, add it to your desktop or to a panel, and go to *veromix settings*, select PulseAudio tab and select the higher volume range that you want (up to 255% is allowed, it is not recommended going higher than 200 as that may damage the speakers). Hit <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>Ok</kbd>.

> You may need to toogle a bit for the changes to take effect. For example, in my case, after I set the volume to 255, I went to the widget and selected an arrow pointing left, right next to the volume bar. Selected unlock channels, and repeated the process (I locked the channels again), that way the volume bar allowed me to set the volume to 255%.

[image: 255%Volume www.notio.cf]